# ipython in emacs no figure output

Tags: emacs, ipython

i am using emacs 24.3 under windows, ipython 0.13.1, python 2.7.3
i use the python.el with emacs withe the following configure the ipython shell

```lisp
;; setup ipython for default interpreter
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:/Python27/python")
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "-i C:/Python27/Scripts/ipython-script.py --pylab")
(setq python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: ")
(setq python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: ")
(setq python-shell-completion-setup-code "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion")
(setq python-shell-completion-module-string-code "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n")
(setq python-shell-completion-string-code "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
```

it works pretty well, except just no figure output...[image]
does anyone experience the same here? solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the real solution is modify

```lisp
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "-i C:/Python27/Scripts/ipython-script.py --pylab")
```

to

```lisp
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "-i C:/Python27/Scripts/ipython-script.py console --pylab")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Qt4Agg backend (see the welcome to message).  That means you should see a window showing the plot.  If not, I suggest you to write a script and execute it outside of Emacs and IPython to localize the problem.

If you want to see plots in Emacs, you can do it with my plugin called [EIN](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook).

[image: screen shot]

Comment: i do see a figure window popup, but then it freezes without any real plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    pyplot.show(block=True)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add

```lisp
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "-i C:/Python27/Scripts/ipython-script.py --pylab=inline")
```